# How to hide innerHTML after few seconds?

Tags: javascript, delay, innerhtml, solution

I wanted to hide innerHTML "Unfollowed" after few seconds and then display "Follow" again.

```
var clicked = false;
document.getElementById("followbutton").addEventListener("click", function(){
  if (clicked==false){
    document.getElementById("followbutton").innerHTML = "Followed"
    clicked=true;
  }else if (clicked==true){
    document.getElementById("followbutton").innerHTML = "UnFollowed".hide().delay(3000).fadeIn('slow');
    document.getElementById("followbutton").innerHTML = "Follow";
    clicked=false;
  }
})
```

this code is just not working I am just lacking the knowledge to get it done.
If you could help that would mean a lot thank you.

Comment: "this code is just not working" is not a great description of the problem. What is happening that shouldn't? What isn't happening that should? What console errors do you get? `hide()` is not a native JavaScript function for a start, are you using jquery?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot chain jQuery functions like hide(), delay(), and fadeIn() to a plain JavaScript statement like innerHTML, you'll need to wrap the element in a jQuery object first.

So the issue is that the hide, delayed and fadeIn are being ignored.

this should work:

```
var clicked = false;
document.getElementById("followbutton").addEventListener("click", function(){
  if (clicked == false){
    document.getElementById("followbutton").innerHTML = "Followed";
    clicked = true;
  } else {
    $("#followbutton").html("UnFollowed").delay(3000).fadeOut('slow', function() {
      $(this).html("Follow").fadeIn('slow');
      clicked = false;
    });
  }
});
```

In this version, the button element is wrapped in a jQuery object.

Comment: Thank you so much. That actually helped me understand my error. And it works!

Answer (score 0):

When manipulating the DOM, you can grab the element you want to manipulate and save it in a variable, like so:

```
let followBtn = document.getElementById('followbutton');
```

That way you don't have to keep writing document.getElementById... over and over again.

```
const followBtn = document.getElementById("follow-btn");

followBtn.addEventListener('click', function toggleFollow() {
  if (followBtn.classList.contains('inactive')) {
  followBtn.innerHTML = 'Unfollow';
  followBtn.classList.remove('inactive');
    followBtn.classList.add('active')
setTimeout(toggleFollow, 3000)
  } else {
    followBtn.innerHTML = 'Follow';
    followBtn.classList.add('inactive')
  }
  clearTimeout(toggleFollow)
})
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: None of this answers the question. Kebab case won't make a difference. Using `let` instead of `var` here won't make a difference either. And defining a new variable for `document.getElementById('followbutton')` won't fix anything.

Comment: Heard. I'm sorry, I'll make sure to be clearer in the future

Comment: and i'll edit this, of course. thanks for the heads up